# Polycom VOIP phone seems to mask the secondary device's MAC address from a Cisco switch

Tags: arp, mac-address, cisco-catalyst, polycom, network-management

When I have a Polycom VOIP phone plugged into a Cisco switch and a laptop plugged into the Polycom phone I get the following.

1) The phone goes into the voice VLAN as expected.

2) The laptop goes into the data VLAN as expected.

3) When I run
show mac-address-table

on the Cisco switch I get the Polycom's MAC address listed twice, as belonging to both VLAN's.

4) When I run
show ip arp

on the Cisco switch I get two IP's and two MAC's listed for the Polycom phone and the laptop.

I have the following questions:

1) Given that the Polycom phone is just an Ethernet bridge why is it that the MAC detection fails to catch the laptop's MAC address?

2) How can I fix that if at all?

The bigger picture is that I am trying to get PacketFence to view and manage the two devices (the phone and the laptop) individually and the way it is it just does not seem to be possible.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Boris.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that dot1x vs SNMP is what makes a difference there. dot1x communicates the addition/disconnect of bridged devices. Now why that is I have no clue - but at least that is a solution of sorts